# AJAX JQUERY Simple Get gives me a Error 405

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to collect a token from a url by giving it the parameters ClientID and ClientSecret using a POST method.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(function(){

    $.ajax({
        "type":"POST",
        "url":"*******",
        "data":{clientID:"*****",clientSecret:"*****"}, 
        success:function(datos){ 
             console.log("Funciona")
         },
        "dataType": "json"
    })
})
```

However, when I run it I get error 405. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: JSONP is **very very limited**. It does not support POST requests or custom headers. You are getting a Method Not Allowed error because you are making a GET request and the server expects a POST request. (This indicates that the server doesn't support JSONP so you shouldn't be trying to make a JSONP request in the first place).

Comment: *Aside* `"crossDomain": true,` has no useful effect unless you are making a *same origin*, non-JSONP request that gets **redirected** to be cross-origin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I have changed the "type" to GET, removed the "dataType" jsonp and removed the "crossDomain". But it still gives error 405, any idea?

Comment: I said "You are getting a Method Not Allowed error because you are making a GET request". Changing the code to explicitly use GET instead of doing it implicitly via JSONP still means you are making a GET request (which the server says is not allowed).

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry, I'm new to javascript. Its supposed I have to collect a token from a respective page. If the server says a GET request is not allowed. How could I collect the token then?

Comment: Presumably by making a POST request.

Comment: I thought I was making a POST request when I put it in type

Comment: Read the first two sentences of my first comment again.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your patience :)

Comment: I have edited the code, understanding your comments. What do you think?

Comment: Now it should make a POST request. You've completely changed where the data is passed though.

Comment: Is it still ok to pass the clientId and clientSecret that way or is it wrong?

Comment: I have no idea how the API you are using expects the values to be passed. All I know is that it responds to GET requests with Method Not Allowed.

Comment: You are helping me a lot, thanks for your time. What other ways are there to pass the data to the API besides this one?

Comment: APIs in general: Too many to enumerate. The API you are using: How should I know? It should have documentation; use it.